# UISearchController Hide Search Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchController in my UITableViewController. I'd like the search bar to be hidden until the user scrolls down. In the old UISearchDisplayController, I had the following code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
//Hides the search bar until user manually scrolls up.
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
```

Unfortunately, the above code no longer works with the UISearchController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out the problem. The below is wrong,

```
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
```

it should be

```
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
```

Instead of self.searchBar, it needs to be self.searchController.searchBar